# How to make Aquamacs open target of alias

Tags: alias, aquamacs

When opening a file with `C-x C-f` in Aquamacs, if I enter the pathname of an alias, the new buffer that appears is filled with gibberish (I guess this is the contents of the alias itself). What can I do to open the target of the alias instead?

To put it another way, I’d like Aquamacs to behave the same when I `C-x C-f` an existing pathname as when I double-click on an Aquamacs-associated file icon in the Finder.

(A method of opening aliased and non-aliased files by the same means would be best.)